# Cannot restart an stopped app run on Google Cloud App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have deployed an python app on Google Cloud App Engine through GLC. Because I needed to spend a lot of time to update the code, I disabled the app in the settings under IAM & Admin in Google Cloud Console. However, after updating my code and testing it locally. I cannot find a way to redeploy the app.

I used the following command of GLC to redeployit:

glcoud app deploy

But I got the following error:
Unable to deploy to application  with status [USER_DISABLED]: Deploying to stopped apps is not allowed.

I then used

glcoud app create

I got the following error:
ERROR: (gcloud.app.create) The project already contains an App Engine application in region [australia-southeast1].  You can deploy your application using `gcloud app deploy`.

Comment: I think you didn't disabled the app but deleted the complete project. That's the only thing you can do in Settings under IAM & Admin. Check https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-projects#restoring_a_project

Comment: Can you detail what did you do with IAM and APp Engine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to go to https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine/settings, select the project and then click 'Enable Application'.

To disable it, use the same path and click on 'Disable Application'

[image]